# R improve loop efficiency: Operating on columns that correspond to rows in a second dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, coding-efficiency, tidytable

I have two data frames:

```
dat <- data.frame(Digits_Lower = 1:5,
                  Digits_Upper = 6:10,
                  random = 20:24)
dat
#>   Digits_Lower Digits_Upper random
#> 1            1            6     20
#> 2            2            7     21
#> 3            3            8     22
#> 4            4            9     23
#> 5            5           10     24

cb <- data.frame(Digits = c("Digits_Lower", "Digits_Upper"),
                 x = 1:2, 
                 y = 3:4)
cb                 
#>         Digits x y
#> 1 Digits_Lower 1 3
#> 2 Digits_Upper 2 4
```

I am trying to perform some operation on multiple columns in `dat` similar to these examples: [In data.table: iterating over the rows of another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448908/in-data-table-iterating-over-the-rows-of-another-data-table) and [R multiply columns by values in second dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428440/r-multiply-columns-by-values-in-second-dataframe). However, I
am hoping to operate on these columns with an extended expression for every value in its corresponding row in `cb`. The solution should be applicable
for a large dataset. I have created this `for-loop` so far.

```
dat.loop <- dat
for(i in seq_len(nrow(cb)))
{
#create new columns from the Digits column of `cb`
  dat.loop[paste0("disp", sep = '.', cb$Digits[i])] <- 
    #some operation using every value in a column in `dat` with its corresponding row in `cb` 
    (dat.loop[, cb$Digits[i]]- cb$y[i]) * cb$x[i]
}
dat.loop 
#>   Digits_Lower Digits_Upper random disp.Digits_Lower disp.Digits_Upper
#> 1            1            6     20                -2                 4
#> 2            2            7     21                -1                 6
#> 3            3            8     22                 0                 8
#> 4            4            9     23                 1                10
#> 5            5           10     24                 2                12
```

I will then perform operations on the data that I appended to `dat` in `dat.loop` applying a similar
`for-loop`, and then perform yet another operation on those values. My dataset is very large, and I imagine
my use of for-loops will become cumbersome. I am wondering:

1. Would another method improve efficiency such as using `data.table` or `tidyverse`?
2. How would I go about using another method, or improving my for-loop? My main confusion is how to write concise code
   to perform operations on columns in `dat` with corresponding rows in `cb`. Ideally, I would split my for-loop into
   multiple functions that would for example, avoid indexing into `cb` for the same values over and over again or appending unnecessary data to my dataframe, but I'm not really sure how to
   do this.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I've modified the code @Desmond provided allowing for more generic code since `dat` and `cb` will be from user-inputted files,
and `dat` can have a varying number of columns/ column names that I will be operating on (columns in `dat` will always start with
"Digits_" and will be specified in the "Digits" column of `cb`.

```
library(tidytable)

results <- dat %>% 
  crossing.(cb) %>% 
  mutate_rowwise.(disp = (get(`Digits`)-y) *x ) %>%
  pivot_wider.(names_from = Digits,
              values_from = disp,
              names_prefix = "disp_")

results2 <- results %>% 
  fill.(starts_with("disp"), .direction = c("downup"), .by = 'random') %>% 
  select.(-c(x,y)) %>% 
  distinct.()
              
results2
#>   Digits_Lower Digits_Upper random disp_Digits_Lower disp_Digits_Upper
#> 1            1            6     20                -2                 4
#> 2            2            7     21                -1                 6
#> 3            3            8     22                 0                 8
#> 4            4            9     23                 1                10
#> 5            5           10     24                 2                12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

- `crossing` generates combinations from both datasets
- `case_when` to apply your logic
- `pivot_wider`, `filter` and `bind_cols` to clean up the output

To scale this to a large dataset, I suggest using the [tidytable package](https://markfairbanks.github.io/tidytable/). After loading it, simply replace `crossing()` with `crossing.()`, `pivot_wider()` with `pivot_wider.()`, etc

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.2.1
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.1

dat <- data.frame(
  Digits_Lower = 1:5,
  Digits_Upper = 6:10,
  random = 20:24
)

cb <- data.frame(
  Digits = c("Digits_Lower", "Digits_Upper"),
  x = 1:2,
  y = 3:4
)

results <- dat |>
  crossing(cb) |>
  mutate(disp = case_when(
    Digits == "Digits_Lower" ~ (Digits_Lower - y) * x,
    Digits == "Digits_Upper" ~ (Digits_Upper - y) * x
  )) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Digits,
              values_from = disp,
              names_prefix = "disp_")

results |>
  filter(!is.na(disp_Digits_Lower)) |>
  select(-c(x, y, disp_Digits_Upper)) |> 
  bind_cols(results |> 
              filter(!is.na(disp_Digits_Upper)) |> 
              select(disp_Digits_Upper))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   Digits_Lower Digits_Upper random disp_Digits_Lower disp_Digits_Upper
#>          <int>        <int>  <int>             <int>             <int>
#> 1            1            6     20                -2                 4
#> 2            2            7     21                -1                 6
#> 3            3            8     22                 0                 8
#> 4            4            9     23                 1                10
#> 5            5           10     24                 2                12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much for your solution! I am working on applying it to my larger dataset and will let you know if I have any comments/ questions

Comment: I'm wondering how to apply this code if `dat` can have a variable number of columns and names following the "Digits_" pattern. I tried to clarify what I mean with an edit but am happy to provide more information, thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure I follow - could you give me an example of your ideal output please? And modifications to `dat` and `cb`, if any.

Comment: I figured it out modifying your code, shown in an edit. Thanks again for your help!